# Python: extract all placeholders from format string

Tags: regex, parsing, python-2.x, string-formatting

I have to 'parse' a format string in order to extract the variables.

E.g.

```
>>> s = "%(code)s - %(description)s"
>>> get_vars(s)
'code', 'description'
```

I managed to do that by using regular expressions:

```
re.findall(r"%\((\w+)\)", s)
```

but I wonder whether there are built-in solutions (actually Python do parse the string in order to evaluate it!).

Comment: I recommend you use the new python 3 string format instead, where both `string.Formatter` and a parse module: https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse are available.

Comment: Please, give a reason for -1: it will help me to improve my questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work great:

```
def get_vars(s):
    d = {}
    while True:
        try:
            s % d
        except KeyError as exc:
            # exc.args[0] contains the name of the key that was not found;
            # 0 is used because it appears to work with all types of placeholders.
            d[exc.args[0]] = 0
        else:
            break
    return d.keys()
```

gives you:

```
>>> get_vars('%(code)s - %(description)s - %(age)d - %(weight)f')
['age', 'code', 'description', 'weight']
```

Comment: +1 This is surely a good solution, but still uses a 'trick'; isn't there any native solution?

Comment: I doubt there's anything in the stdlib; you can take a peek inside the CPython source though to see how the `%` operator is implemented for `basestring` and if it's potentially reusable from outside `basestring` itself. If not, any 3rd party solutions should be, in principle, just as fragile (or reliable) as this trick here.